# Force uninstall of Visual Studio 2015 after deleting files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uninstallation

So I wanted to uninstall Visual Studio, but for some reason the uninstaller wouldn't work. I tried methods I saw online, such as command prompt, however nothing I saw worked. After much MUCH frustration, I did the one thing you should never do. Try to manually delete all of the files. Long story short, it didn't work either, and now I'm getting more errors than before.

I know I'm an idiot for trying that, but does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem? I re-installed it on a virtual machine and am forced to use it there, but my virtual machines aren't that reliable.

Comment: You can have a try with the VisualStudioUnistaller: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller and after that, run the command: sfc /scannow to verify the integrity of the OS, and run this tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed to fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed.

Comment: I tried both of these. The first program had an error when running, and the second one found errors and stopped. I got Visual Studio 2017 now, so I don't really need to uninstall it. It's not taking up that much space.